# Show Product Category Item List in Static Block (cms block)

Tags: product-list, static-block

I try to show the product list from my category ID 472 somewhere else of my magento Site, so I've made a Static-Block who includes:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="472" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

At my phtml-Template I include the Block like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('telekomm_success')->toHTML();?>
```

But there's no HTML Output. only the first  from the "catalog/product/list.phtml"-Template. Why?
What do I wrong?

Comment: Check var/log for errors. If you get a partial output, most likely there is a fatal error that stops the execution. Activate developer mode and you should see the error in the page.

Comment: I see .. "Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in /.../app/design/frontend/client/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml on line 41" but I've no problems with my "list-template" at all?  toolbar? Line 41: "<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>"

Comment: I take another template and I get my result. There must be an error at my list-template (toolbar)?!